# List of checkboxes Symfony 4

Tags: php, list, checkbox, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony 4 and I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes with a searcher in the following situation:

I have an entity called **SAI**, and this entity may be "owned" by many users (so, I have an entity called **User**).
I have a controller **AddSAIController.php** where I manage how to add a SAI. And when I add it, I want to display a form in which the user can enter the serial_number of the SAI and can check what users own that SAI. The problem is that I will have a lot of users in the database and I would need a searcher to find faster the users I want.

First of all I tried to create the list of checkboxes following the documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html, I have managed to get to show the users, but not with checkboxes as I wanted, instead, it shows them like a input text type.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf9to.png)
This is my code:

**add_sais.html.twig**

```
{%  block body %}

<div class="main">
    <h1>Add SAI</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="formUsers">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {% for user in form.users %}
            {{ form_row(user.username) }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>

{%  endblock %}
```

**AddSAIsController.php**

```
public function addSAI(Request $request)
{
    $sai = new SAI();
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    $sai->setUsers($users); 
    $form = $this->createForm(SAIType::class,$sai);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('management/add_sais.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**UsersType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('username');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ));
}
```

**SAIType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('serial_number');
    $builder->add('users', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => UsersType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => SAI::class,
    ));
}
```

For now I would be happy with some help to create the checkboxes, I will do the seracher later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do to have a multiple selector and a search function in one is use a jQuery selectbox plugin, for example Select2. This gives you a select field where you can search and have multiple inputs. Try this:

**SAIType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('serial_number')
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => User::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true']
    ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => SAI::class,
    ));
}
```

Then on the page you want to use it (or just put it in `base.html.twig`):

**CSS**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('select[data-select="true"]').select2({});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I have managed to do it, and everything works but the searching, I don't see any option to search for a user. It shows the list of users [like this](https://i.gyazo.com/0f00f62bdc9987beb9616f16516ce4ea.png) and it works when I select any of them, but I can't search.  
Any idea what it could be? Thanks!

Comment: Check if you haven't forgotten the part `'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true']` or any of the two javascripts on the page you render the form. It should look like a single input field where you can search and select.

Comment: The SAIType.php file is exactly the same as you told me. My add_sais.html.twig looks like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/8fd56c56c0fefc49d0e5c9f708dbde42.png).  
In fact, if I delete the script it still works, so I guess it is not detected somehow.  
Don't worry if you don't see any mistake there, I won't bother you anymore :D, eventually I will find what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. First of all, your javascript should be in the block 'javascripts', not your body block. This should be "{% block javascripts %} ....this is where your javascript goes... {% endblock %}. Secondly, your css should go in your CSS block, just like with the javascript block. Finally, if you don't have it already, you need to include jQeury. Put this in your <head>: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You are right, it works now! I had no idea that I had to make a block even for javascript. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad i could help!